# Does a reference to a delegate constitute a reference to an object (to prevent garbage collection)?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, garbage-collection

I had trouble coming up with a good way to word this question, so let me try to explain by example:

Suppose I have some interface. For simplicity's sake, I'll say the interface is `IRunnable`, and it provides a single method, `Run`. (This is not real; it's only an example.)

Now, suppose I have some pre-existing class, let's call it `Cheetah`, that I can't change. It existed before `IRunnable`; I can't *make* it implement my interface. But I want to use it *as if* it implements `IRunnable`--presumably because it has a `Run` method, or something like it. In other words, I want to be able to have code that expects an `IRunnable` and will work with a `Cheetah`.

OK, so I could always write a `CheetahWrapper` sort of deal. But humor me and let me write something a little more flexible--how about a `RunnableAdapter`?

I envision the class definition as something like this:

```
public class RunnableAdapter : IRunnable {
    public delegate void RunMethod();

    private RunMethod Runner { get; set; }

    public RunnableAdapter(RunMethod runner) {
        this.Runner = runner;
    }

    public void Run() {
        Runner.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Straightforward enough, right? So with this, I should be able to make a call like this:

```
Cheetah c = new Cheetah();
RunnableAdapter ra = new RunnableAdapter(c.Run);
```

And now, voila: I have an object that implements `IRunner` and is, in its heart of hearts, a `Cheetah`.

My question is: if this `Cheetah` of mine falls out of scope at some point, and gets to the point where it would normally be garbage collected... will it? Or does this `RunnableAdapter` object's `Runner` property constitute a reference to the original `Cheetah`, so that it won't be collected? I certainly want that reference to stay valid, so basically I'm wondering if the above class definition is enough or if it would be necessary to maintain a reference to the underlying object (like via some private `UnderlyingObject` property), just to prevent garbage collection.

Comment: Wow, pretty ridiculous I forgot to put those tags... yes, fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that reference remains valid, and can in fact be retrieved using the Delegate.Target property -- in your code, as `ra.Runner.Target`.

Answer (score 4):

As others said it counts as a reference. You might find this story interesting.
http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2008/11/garbage-collection-causes-car-crash.html

Comment: Wow, that's... pretty darn definitive.

Answer (score 2):

If not, that sounds like a broken garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the delegate counts as a reference. Your object will not be garbage collected until the delegate is also unreachable.